# Verifying Bitcoin Knots download using GPG4Win

Tags: pgp, bitcoin, gpg4win

I'm trying to install [Bitcoin Knots](https://bitcoinknots.org/), but the process of key validation is new to me.

What I did:

- Downloaded and ran Kleopatra: https://gpg4win.org/get-gpg4win.html
- Download Bitcoin Knots for Windows:  https://bitcoinknots.org/
- Downloaded Signature File: https://bitcoinknots.org/files/26.x/26.1.knots20240325/SHA256SUMS.asc
- Downloaded achow101.gpg from: https://github.com/bitcoin-core/guix.sigs/tree/main/builder-keys
- Imported Public Keys into Kleopatra: “File > Import Certificates” imported achow101.gpg
- In Kleopatra: “File > Decrypt/Verify Files”
- Selected the downloaded: `SHA256SUMS.asc`
- Then select `bitcoin-26.1.knots20240325-win64-setup-unsigned.exe`

I get this error:

> Verified ‘bitcoin-26.1.knots20240325-win64-setup-unsigned.exe’ with ‘SHA256SUMS.asc’:
> The data could not be verified.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You're verifying the wrong file – `SHA256SUMS.asc` is a signature for the `SHA256SUMS` file, not for any of the individual installer files (which the program's publishers have decided not to sign).

Verify the SHA256SUMS file using GnuPG, and if that passes, then use any hash calculator app to verify the SHA-256 of the installer. (Linux has `sha256sum -c` to check against a list of hashes.)

Comment: Ok, sorry for the noob question but I only have the `SHA256SUMS.asc` file. If I click "Decrypt/Verify" and select that file I get another popup to select another file. Not sure what I need to do there?
And I'm on Windows which does not seem to have `sha256sum -c`

Comment: Then download the SHA256SUMS file from the same place as the other two files: https://bitcoinknots.org/files/26.x/26.1.knots20240325/

Comment: Thanks. So I downloaded this file: https://bitcoinknots.org/files/26.x/26.1.knots20240325/SHA256SUMS to `SHA256SUMS.txt`. When I then verify I get:
`Verified ‘SHA256SUMS.txt’ with ‘SHA256SUMS.asc’: The data could not be verified. Signature created on Wednesday, March 27, 2024 01:47:17
With unavailable certificate:
ID: 0x1A3E761F19D2CC7785C5502EA291A2C45D0C504A
You can search the certificate on a keyserver or import it from a file.`